# How much damage is caused to a laptop under load?

Tags: linux, laptop, vmware-fusion

So I am playing around in VMWare to practice some networking, this is all done on a macbook pro 2015 (Hardware spec is kind of irrelevant for this post)
So the CPU does run a bit hot at around 80 degrees C, the VMs are stored on an external HDD (SATA 2.5" HDD via USB).
So running under such load what damage would be expected if any was to occur and would/could it reduce the lifespan of the laptop?
I am not exceeding the specification of the laptop as the VMs have been given 1 core and 2048 and 1024MB of RAM respectively.

Thanks

Comment: Incorrect, 80C is fine for Macbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Macbooks are designed to run hot...up to 100 degrees celsius and more. It won't do any damage to the hardware but it can most certainly give slight burns to your body if you use it as a "laptop". You can mitigate the heat factor by getting a cradle that lifts the Macbook off a surface; therefor creating more surface area for heat to dissipate, but its not needed. I have been running a circa 2010 Macbook under regular loads of 110-130C with no problem.

Macbooks actually run much hotter **natively** than virtually any other notebook on the market. They are engineered to run hot.

Comment: If you are still worried, follow the guidelines here: http://www.macworld.com/article/2036285/advice-from-an-apple-tech-when-your-mac-gets-too-toasty.html

Comment: I have it on a desk when I am running VMs, I also have an extra fan at the ready if need be as the office I am in is very hot.

Comment: Oh and in addition, I looked on Intel Ark and its rated at a 105 degrees maximum, I have mac fan control to keep it at 80 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Macbook Pro? I had a 2009 Macbook (non pro) that used to get over 80 (max 88) and stay there for longer time when playing video or doing something resource intensive. The same model (body) is still sold, but that is non retina.

I used a temperature monitor app to see what happened. It never caused any issues, for years. It was unpleasant, and I had to use some kind of holder to protect my legs because it got too hot.

My new 2015 Macbook Pro Retina does not get hotter than 67 degrees C, but maybe I haven't tested it properly yet.

See this tip to [**cool things down**](https://superuser.com/a/1094007/39436) a bit.